# Cannot find text in Legend tag

Tags: html, google-chrome

When I do a site search in Google Chrome for text on a page Chrome does not find the text if it is within a legend tag. Take this example:

```html
<body>
  Hello Earth
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Hello World</legend>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>
```

In firefox when I press `CTRL` + `F` and search for "Hello" it finds 2 instances. In chrome when I do the same thing it only finds the one outside of the legend tag.

In another example: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_fieldset

Chrome only finds one instance of "personalia". Firefox finds 2.

Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

Comment: Could be a bug with chrome or it's meant to be that way, better ask google.

Comment: @Huangism I just submitted the bug report to Google in case it is on their end. In the meantime, if anyone else has info about this it would be appreciated.

Comment: I too am having this problem. @Lee: has Google responded to your bug report?

Comment: @tb-mtg I have not gotten a response from Google.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same! So weird. I hope the bug gets fixed.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same.
@Lee Can you provide link to Google bug's issue?

Comment: This one isn't mine but here is one link: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/6256714?hl=en

Comment: I started experiencing the same issue while it worked before.